# Tomcat JSP authentication fails

Tags: jsp, tomcat, authentication

I have a Tomcat 7.0.52 server running. In it there is a File Browser (http://www.vonloesch.de/filebrowser.html it's a bit old but it does what I need it to do)

However, I want to password protect the browser and not store the password as plain text so I have updated the Realm section as follows:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           digest="SHA-1" digestEncoding="UTF-8"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

The File Browser was installed in ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/Browser/index.jsp

Then I created the file ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/Browser/WEB-INF/web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">

  <display-name>Browser</display-name>
  <description>A JSP file manager for Tomcat</description>

  <!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
  <security-role>
    <role-name>browser</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <!-- Define a Security Constraint on this Application -->
  <!-- NOTE:  None of these roles are present in the default users file -->
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Browser</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>browser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>

</web-app>
```

And finally, I added the following lines to the  section in the ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<role rolename="browser"/>
<user username="fadmin" password="...pw hash removed..." roles="browser"/>
```

The tomcat-users.xml file also contains information for accessing the Tomcat manager page. Also I have checked the web.xml I created against the web.xml of the Tomcat manager and the ,  and  sections look very similar

Now, when I access the Tomcat manager page, I get a username/password box and when I enter the correct credentials I get access to the manager page. However, when I try to access the Browser page, I don't get the username/password box but I immediately get a 403 page with the following content:

```
HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message Access to the requested resource has been denied

description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
```

What am I doing wrong?

As per request, here is the contents of the tomcat-users.xml file (I did leave out the comments though and removed the password hashes)

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="tcadmin" password="...pw hash removed..." roles="tomcat,admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="browser"/>
  <user username="fadmin" password="...pw hash removed..." roles="browser"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Please provide the complete content (you can still hide the hashes) of the tomcat-users.xml file.

Comment: @MarkThomas, I have added the contents of the tomcat-users.xml file at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: The point of asking for the full file was that by default all the users are commented out and folks often miss that. Now you have removed the comments we can't check whether that was the problem.

Comment: @MarkThomas, I now understand your reasoning. Fortunately, there turned out to be no fault in the tomcat-users.xml file as you have read in my own answer. But Thanx for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the solution was so simple......

Restart Tomcat after changing the tomcat-users.xml

Now it works as expected.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't monitor that file for changes so you will need to trigger a reload. Restarting is the simplest way of doing that. You can also add/remove users, groups and roles via JMX and that takes effect immediately.